# retrieve ajax pagination on click browser back button in laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, browser, pagination

I have implemented the Laravel pagination through ajax and its working fine but the problem is when I am at page 2 and click to view the result from page 2 then want to back to the result listing then it returns to page 1 instead of page 2.
Here is my code.

```
$(document).on('click','.pagination a',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({
            url : url,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
              $('#id').html(data);
            }
        });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly what is the problem from only this code but i have a great tutorial about laravel pagination with ajax here:
https://www.webslesson.info/2018/09/laravel-pagination-using-ajax.html

Also there is a jquery plugin called DataTables it is very easy and useful when dealing with data and here is the link:
https://datatables.net/

Comment: I have no issue with the ajax pagination implementation. I have implemented the same and its working fine but the problem is when I am at page 2 and click to view the result from page 2 then want to back to the result listing then it returns to page 1 instead of page 2.